# Having error during use ispconfig auto installer in debian 11

Tags: debian, ispconfig-3

```
[WARN] Query CREATE DATABASE phpmyadmin; failed. (/lib/os/class.ISPConfigDebianOS.inc.php:339)[WARN] Query CREATE USER 'pma'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'uUFMzprRqDAZm1B'; failed. (/lib/os/class.ISPConfigDebianOS.inc.php:339)
[INFO] HTTPoxy config.
[INFO] Installing acme.sh (Let's Encrypt).
[INFO] acme.sh (Let's Encrypt) installed.
[INFO] Installing packages quota, quotatool, haveged, geoip-database, libclass-dbi-mysql-perl, libtimedate-perl, build-essential, autoconf, automake, libtool, flex, bison, debhelper, binutils
[INFO] Installed packages quota, quotatool, haveged, geoip-database, libclass-dbi-mysql-perl,
libtimedate-perl, build-essential, autoconf, automake, libtool, flex, bison, debhelper, binutils
[INFO] Adding quota to fstab.
[ERROR] Exception occured: ISPConfigOSException -> Command mount -o remount / 2>&1 && quotaoff -avug 2>&1 && quotacheck -avugm 2>&1 && quotaon -avug 2>&1 failed. (/ispconfig.ai.php:15)
```

Having this problem whem I'm using ispconfig autoinstaller command below
`curl https://get.ispconfig.org | sh -s -- --debug --no-mailman` 
Also tried without debug.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use su -  that solved the issue for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

add --no-quota to the end of the installation code like this

`wget -O - https://get.ispconfig.org | sh -s -- --use-ftp-ports=40110-40210 --unattended-upgrades --no-quota`